# Following the next link when finished loading PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically,

I visit a web page, that web page is loading...

When It's finished loading it directs you to the new link.

So my questions is,

How can I get that second link HTML code?

I mean I know I can use this:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

connection = urlopen("link").read()

print connection


...
```

But I don't know how to continue to the next web page.

** IMPORTANT **

I DO NOT know the second link because it has an ID that is randomly generated from the first link (main page while it's loading).

So I can't visit it directly, only from the main page until it's loading then go there somehow.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inkluding a example webpage where this problem exists?

Comment: Here's the web page I'm talking about
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

I know how to search a link in the code.
But, if I use the code (the one I wrote in this thread) it would give me the loading screen HTML code, not the result code when it re-directs you.

Comment: If it's a redirect, have you tried using `connection.geturl()`?

Comment: The code that redirects you to a new page will probably be wrapped on a javascript block inside the html source.

Comment: I will try geturl()

but also I tried looking into HTML code but it's no luck.